# On proving that $\sup_{x \in ] -1, 1[} \{ x^{n+1}+ x^{n+2}+ \dots + x^{n+p} \} = p $ .

Tags: real-analysis

As a step to complete an exercise I would like to prove that the $$\sup_{x \in ] -1, 1[} \{ x^{n+1}+ x^{n+2}+ \dots + x^{n+p} \} = p $$

I am a bit stuck on how to do this, anybody mind showing me how?

Comment: The $\sup$ isn't $p-1$ , is $p$.

Comment: thank you both I will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: you can ignore the $x$ with $x<0$ (why?) and $x\mapsto x^{n+1}+ x^{n+2}+ \cdots + x^{n+p}$ is increasing for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks yes I think I see where you are pointing me (taking the limit as $x \rightarrow 1$ correct?). So is there an analogue to the monotone convergence theorem for functions? I still can't seem to formalize it well.

Comment: @Monolite, the $\le p$ is obvious. Suppose the inequality is strict...

Comment: Oh so it's increasing and strictly bounded by $p$, so if I take the limit as $x \rightarrow 1$ I obtain $p$ and it's impossible that I could obtain something more because otherwise there would be a positive distance between $p$ and the limit and for an $\epsilon$ smaller than that positive quantity I can't find any response.

Comment: So what is this theorem called (the supremum on an increasing interval of a function is equal to the limit of the function taken as x goes to the endpoint of the set) ? By the way thank you very much.

Comment: @Monolite, I don't know any "official" name.